# Couchbase installation failing (windows)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, couchbase

I am trying to install Couchbase on Windows 10 I am unable to complete the install process:

**I've tried:**

```
python -m pip install couchbase
python -m pip install git+git://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client
```

**Error:**

```
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -I..\lcb-winbuild\x64\deps\include -IC:\Users\allynh\my_project\\venv\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python36\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python36\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\exceptions.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src\exceptions.obj
exceptions.c
c:\users\allynh\appdata\local\temp\pip-hftjqesn-build\src\pycbc.h(91): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\allynh\my_project\\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\allynh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-hftjqesn-build\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\allynh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-louphgm2-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\allynh\my_project\\venv\include\site\python3.6\couchbase" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\allynh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hftjqesn-build\
```

I presume this is failing because I don't have libcouchbase installed but I can't figure out how to install this. I presume I need to install the [Windows binary package](https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/c-sdk#story-h2-2) but I'm not sure how to do that...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are Windows installers at https://pypi.org/project/couchbase/#files. Try them first.

If you really need to install from sources you need to have a number of [prerequisites](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client#prerequisites):

- Couchbase Server;
- libcouchbase. version 2.8.0 or greater (Bundled in Windows installer);
- libcouchbase development files;
- Python development files.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!

However I'm not sure what to do with this.

There seems to be no version available for python 3.6.
I've installed via the python 2.7 version to test it out but I'm unsure how to actually get the python modules working? 
Do I still need to `pip install git+git://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client`? 
When I try to install `couchbase-python-client` I'm still getting the error:

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h': No such file or directory`